# How to fix FileNotFound error while running pytest

Tags: python-3.x, file, pytest, file-not-found

I am trying to write tests for my project but i get back the FileNotFound Error when running the test.
test is in the folder test. file and code it is testing is in project folder. i cant reference the file as project/file because then my code breaks. anyone any ideas how to fix this?

filename = ('postcode_File.xlsx') is how it is referenced now in the code

so i tried to reference it as project/file
i als tried to copy the file into the test folder
neither worked[image: This is how my project folder looks]

Answer (score 0):

Add `os.chdir("../project")` in a fixture (or in the test itself)?